# Does every topological space have a fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

We define the fundamental group by a homotopy of loops in a space X. However, this means we are considering path connected spaces. What about spaces that are completely disconnected? Do we say they do not have a fundamental group?

I have been thinking about the integers, specifically, and have not been able to find a concrete result. What are other spaces that would not have a fundamental group?

I have just been introduced to the fundamental group, so I am also rather curious about how we would write the fundamental group of a space that is only locally path connected with at least 2 components.

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article [fundamental groupoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_groupoid) helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the fundamental group isn't really constructed from a space $X$, it's constructed from a space $X$ together with a distinguished point $x_0 \in X$.  If $X$ is totally disconnected then the only loops in $X$ based on $x_0$ will be trivial ones, so $\pi_1(X, x_0) = \{e\}$ (i.e., the trivial  group).

More generally, the same thing shows that if $x$ is an isolated point of any space then the fundamental group based at $x$ will be trivial, but the same space might have other fundamental groups that are not trivial.

It's only for path-connected spaces that we can always speak of "the" fundamental group of $X$.

Comment: Cue Ronnie Brown in 5, 4, 3,...

Comment: Even in path-connected spaces you cannot speak of *the* fundamental group. What results is an isomorphism class of groups. If you want a true group you need a basepoint.

Comment: @Tyrone I certainly agree, yet my impression is that people often speak about "the fundamental group of $X$" anyway when the isomorphism class of the group doesn't depend on the basepoint.